# Redirect Error (.htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use .htaccess file for my REST service but I found that the url are not actually redirected. The web server show

[image: Error Message]

I wanted to use url such as

```
/api/v1/test
```

instead of

```
/api/v1/rest.php?request=test
```

I have already check ***mod_rewrite*** is acutally working.

My *.htaccess* file is as below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule api/v1/(.*)$ api/v1/rest.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

I have already look at [PHP redirecting problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572132/htaccess-not-redirecting-to-error-page) and [Sitemap redirecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739674/htaccess-url-re-write-sitemap-xml-to-sitemap-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this rule instead because it works with me :

```
RewriteRule    api/v1/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    api/v1/rest.php?request=$1
```

try putting .htaccess file in htdocs directory and if the directory api location is

```
C:\xampp\htdcos\xampp\www\api
```

then put the full path in the rule

Comment: do you have other rules in your .htaccess file and OS are you using?

Comment: I don't have other rule in .htaccess file and I am using XAMPP on Windows.

Comment: ,thank

It all work when I put .htaccess file to htdocs directory

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php) site generates `mod_rewrite` for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/v1/([^/]*)$ /api/v1/rest.php?request=$1 [L]
```